# Flow images around images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, microsoft-metro

So here is the site that I'm working on: [metroweb.tk](http://metroweb.tk/)

I'm trying to make a website that looks like the windows 8 metro UI. But I ran into a problem. Bigger app icons will stick out like the notes and the clock icons. How do i make it so that images float around images like they do in the windows 8 metro UI. What would I use, anything with CSS, JS, jQuery or HTML is all fine, I just need a way to fix this issue.

Fell free to look at the source if that helps with providing an answer.

CODE:

HTML:

```
<div id="apps">
        <div id="group1" data-apps="13">
            <div id="name">Apps</div>
            <div id="applist">
                <img class="app" src="AboutMe.png" alt="About Me" height="120" width="120">
                <img class="app" src="Calendar.png" alt="Calendar" height="120" width="248">
                <img class="app" src="Notes.png" alt="Notes" height="248" width="120">
                <img class="app" src="AboutMe.png" alt="About Me" height="120" width="120">
                <img class="app" src="Calendar.png" alt="Calendar" height="120" width="248">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="group2" data-apps="30">
            <div id="name">Group 2 Apps</div>
            <div id="applist">
                <img class="app" src="AboutMe.png" alt="About Me" height="120" width="120">
                <img class="app" src="Time.png" alt="Time" height="248" width="248">
                <img class="app" src="AboutMe.png" alt="About Me" height="120" width="120">
                <img class="app" src="AboutMe.png" alt="About Me" height="120" width="120">
                <img class="app" src="Time.png" alt="Time" height="248" width="248">
                <img class="app" src="AboutMe.png" alt="About Me" height="120" width="120">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#apps {
    font-family: 'open_sans-light';
    margin: 120px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#name {
    font-size: 20px;
}
#applist {
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.app {
    padding: 2px;
}
```

JS:

```
    var height = $(window).height();
    height -= 220;
        var group1Width = $("#group1").attr("data-apps");
        var group2Width = $("#group2").attr("data-apps");
        if (height <= 255) {
            group1Width = group1Width;
            group2Width = group2Width;
        } else if (height <= 383 && height >= 256) {
            group1Width = Math.ceil(group1Width/2);
            group2Width = Math.ceil(group2Width/2);
        } else if (height <= 511 && height >= 384) {
            group1Width = Math.ceil(group1Width/3);
            group2Width = Math.ceil(group2Width/3);
        } else if (height >= 512) {
            group1Width = Math.ceil(group1Width/4);
            group2Width = Math.ceil(group2Width/4);
        } else {
            alert("An unknown error has been encountered!");
        };
    group1Width = group1Width*(120)+(group1Width*8)+44;
    group2Width = group2Width*(120)+(group2Width*8)+44;
    var appsWidth = group1Width+group2Width+40;
    $("#apps").css("height", height + "px")
              .css("width", appsWidth + "px");
    $("#group1").css("float", "left")
                .css("height", height + "px")
                .css("width", group1Width + "px");
    $("#group2").css("float", "left")
                .css("height", height + "px")
                .css("width", group2Width + "px");
```

Comment: You need to copy the relevant code here.  When that link is fixed, or down, or the site changes, this question will no longer have any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [isotope's masonry layout options](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html).

Comment: That is actually exactly what I was looking for.